# text File search and collect data into a text file by batch

Tags: shell, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I  want to search for some file that have start character about the same

and then  I collect all information in file in search and collect it redirect it into 1 txt file.

How do I do it.

Here my trying:

> (dir /s unixinv*.csv do type unixinv*) > summary2.txt

Just like :

> find xxx*
>    if yes collect data >> summary2.txt 
>    else  keep finding 
>    every file in this folder and every sub folder

Thank you I'm  trying to learn about it.

Maybe very bad trying result sometime from me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for /r C:\folder %%a in (*.csv) do type %%a >>summary2.txt && echo. >>summary2.txt
```

If this isn't what you want please give more details.

Comment: @eathapeking It represents the file the loop is currently looking at.